# Joining several collections based in a common id in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a big collections of authors with this structure:

```
- authors (id, profile_id, title, name) -> this are 590 authors
```

I have also 4 collections, with author.id == author_id

```
- sales (id, author_id, salesTotal) 
- subscribers (id, author_id, subscribersTotal)
- futureEvents (id, author_id, scheduledTotal)
- reservations (id, authors_id, reservationsTotal)
```

**Not all authors have sales, subscribers, futureEvents and/or reservations. The collections are not organized in any particular order.**

In order to build the authors Index view, I am making a FOREACH loop through all authors, so I need to join all those five collections into one like this:

**`- authors (id, profile_id, title, name, sales, subscribers, futureEvents, reservations)`**

**How could I joint all those collections based in the author_id**, having in mindt that each collection has different lenght and variate dinamically (new authors could sign in, new sales, subscribers sign in or out, etc) from day to day.
So, the index can show different values from day to day

Any idea how?

**EDIT:**
I am using LARAVEL, those collections are the result of each of a different query. For example:

```
$authorsSubscribers = DB::table('authors')
        ->join('subscriptions', 'subscriptions.author_id', '=', 'authors.id')
        ->groupBy('authors.title')
        ->selectRaw('authors.id, COUNT(subscriptions.author_id) AS Subscribers')
        ->get();
```

As result, my collections have all similar structure, like this one:

```
Collection {#86071 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => {#86015 ▼
      +"id": 16
      +"Subscribers": 269
    }
    1 => {#86016 ▼
      +"id": 49
      +"Subscribers": 269
    }
    2 => {#86017 ▼
      +"id": 20
      +"Subscribers": 269
    }
    3 => {#86018 ▼
      +"id": 10
      +"Subscribers": 269
    }
    4 => {#86019 ▼
      +"id": 11
      +"Subscribers": 269
    }
  ]
}
```

I can not make just one big giant query, because I am grouping (GroupBy, counting (COUNT), adding (SUM) and so on.

Comment: By "collection" do you mean arrays of these objects? Please share some code.

Comment: @Jeto I have edited my questin with the info you requested

Comment: @RafaelMunoz use the eloquent relationship so that you can get subsribers, sales, future events directly.

Comment: @SagarGautam, that will work for collections, except for "Future Events". The problem here will be that I need a "WHERE" in a related table (model). And as far as I know, it is not possible to do something like: WHEREJOIN('date',  '>', now()) or WHERE('other_table.date', '>', now()).  And then I have the same problem, I need to join that collection to the prevoius one

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding the solution I have found. perhaps is useful to anybody.

I have trest array:merge, array_map and array_combine without success. Since the arrays have different structure, lenght and keys it was not possible to map one to one.

So, I just used a Foreach Loop to "loop" through each element of the big collection and second loops to loop through each element comparing if the author_id was equal and if yes append it as an atribute.

```
    foreach ($authors as $author  ) {

        foreach ($sales as $sale) {
            if ($author->id === $sale->authorId) {
                $author['salesTotal'] = $sale->salesTotal;
                $author['salesAmount'] = $sale->salesAmount;
            }
        }

        foreach ($futureEvents as $events) {
            if ($author->id === $events->authorId) {
                $author['futureEvents'] = $events->futureEvents;
            }
        }
        foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
            if ($author->id === $reservation->authorId) {
                $author['reservations'] = $reservation->reservations;
            }
        }
    }
```

In that way I just got ONE big collection to loop through in the frontend. Like this:

```
Author {#43454 ▼
  #attributes: array:14 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "profile_id" => 4
    "title" => "Missourimacejkovic.giles"
    ... lot of other attributes ...
    "created_at" => "2019-02-09 18:49:16"
    "updated_at" => "2019-02-09 18:49:16"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "subscriptions_count" => 2
    "events_count" => 19
    "salesTotal" => "9086"
    "salesAmount" => 200
    "futureEvents" => 9
    "reservations" => 450
  ]
}
```